# How to make full backup of encrypted Lollipop Nexus 5 device?

Tags: backup, 5.0-lollipop, encryption, restore

[This guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818321) describes how to make full backup of whole memory block.

My N5 is encrypted with Android 5.0. As far as I understand new mechanism, it envolves dependency on some external data taken from separate hardware component (part of encryption key). Is it guaranteed that it will not altered after I factory reset and flash Android 4.4 ? And even if it's ok, is it possible finally to restore such backup ? (May be /dev/mmcblck0 is read-only or otherwise restricted due to way hardware-accelerated encryption/decryption works.)

Comment: The question is NOT about how to make full backup in general. It's already described in the guide I referred to. The question is about specifics applied to encrypted Nexus 5.

Comment: Related: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) & [How to backup an Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device?rq=1) & [How to do backups and updates properly with full device encryption?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23948/how-to-do-backups-and-updates-properly-with-full-device-encryption?rq=1)

Comment: I removed the Nexus 5 tag, this would relate to All encrypted devices with android 5.

Comment: You could decrypt the device for a backup, as that would make things much easier and I hope you make backups infrequently. Then do a Nandroid backup, and then reencrypt.

Comment: @Tamogna, it's not possible to decrypt already encrypted device (at least on Marshmallow). Only factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can install TWRP for your nexus 5 (just Google it...).
It will ask you for your password when you enter the recovery. Then you can do a full backup.

Comment: I'm familiar with TWRP a little. It can not do full backup simply because it uses internal storage to save backup data. (At least for Nexus 5.)

Comment: Why you can't copy that backup data to your computer?

Comment: Why? I can. I said it's just not full backup, because it doesn't backup part of memory (userdata partition) used for storing backup being done. That's why I referred to the guide at very start of my question, which describes how to perform block-level copying of whole(!) memory directly to PC.

Comment: @ArtemPisarenko The link you posted shows how to do a backup of the whole memory block (in section "Back up of the whole memory block (via adb)"). That *includes* the userdata partition. You don't need to do it over wifi either. The problem is that userdata is encrypted. So you could instead copy just the decrypted block device, if you enter in the right password for TWRP to decrypt it. And yes, you can do the reverse and write the backed up userdata partition back to the android device.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I found is making unencrypted backups with WugFresh NRT:

- Turn on airplane mode (not related to encryption, just recommendation in order to prevent sudden changes in data during backup)
- Make nandroid full backup (select all partitions available, for 'recovery' partion ROOT required)
- Make data/media backup
- Turn off airplane mode

These backups will be unencrypted.
Restoring process is symmetric and also doesn't depend on whether device encrypted or not.

If you want to keep backup data encrypted, just use encrypted virtual drive (BitLocker, TrueCrypt, etc.).

Comment: How does turning on airplane mode make the partitions unencrypted? Can you link to something that documents this? Also, in order to perform a nandroid backup you have to be in recovery, how do you turn on airplane mode in recovery? The radio would not be on in that state, so the device would already be "in airplane mode".

Comment: @RyanConrad, airplane mode isn't related to encryption, it's just general recommendation for overall process, because it consists of several steps and reboots in different modes (data/media part is done in normal operating mode when radio is on).

Answer (score 0):

Just install CWM Recovery on your device. You will get some options under backup and restore.

[image: cwm recovery]

You can effectively backup your current data/ROM and later restore at any stage.

Comment: Does it allow to import/export data directly(!) to external storage ? (Otherwise I don't see any difference with TWRP.)

Comment: Yes,  it allows backup to external storage.