# Mounting encrypted partition from PC - is there anything I can do?

Tags: recovery-mode, encryption, fastboot, side-loading

Okay, so basically I have the same [problem identified here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125121/mount-android-encrypted-data-partition-on-pc), except instead of a broken screen, I accidentally [broke the UI with this bug](http://forum.xda-developers.com/droid-turbo/general/psa-enable-force-rtl-layout-5-1-t3149244/post61683443#post61683443).

And all I want to do is mount the encrypted partition so I can get some photos from it before I factory reset.

Unfortunately, I never enabled usb debugging, I don't have a custom recovery, I don't have an unlocked bootloader, and I don't have a backup app installed either! (lesson learned)

My device is a Motorola XT1254 and I have Ubuntu on my PC (although I also have other PCs with OSX and windows if that helps at all).

What I've tried so far is fastboot to twrp ([found a version for my device here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-maxx/orig-development/recovery-twrp-2-8-7-0-touch-recovery-t3180308)), like so:

```
sudo fastboot boot twrp-3.0.2.0-quark.img
```

That didn't work, and displayed this in the terminal:

```
OKAY [ 0.390s]
booting...
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.392s
```

So yeah I presume that's because of the locked bootloader. And according to the motorola site, you must erase the internal storage to unlock the bootloader. Is my device rejecting the fastboot because of the locked bootloader, or should I just try a different version of twrp or something else?

Any other ideas? The default recovery for my device has an option to sideload updates from adb which is my only other idea. It sounds like sideload from adb can run a script in the zip file to automatically update specific files on reboot... maybe there's a way to revert the "force RTL" developer setting with it? Is it even possible to do adb sideload if my device is encrypted? Could I use it in some other way to access my encrypted partition?

Also forgive any ignorance on my part, note that this is literally the first time I've done anything technical with android! But I have a pretty decent understand of linux in general.

P.S. my device has no external SD card slot (which seems idiotic but whatever) so anything involving that is out of the question.

Comment: You're in a mess. 1) You presumed correctly. Device didn't load TWRP because bootloader in not unlocked so there is no point in finding out some other version of TWRP. 2) Stock recovery only loads a ZIP [signed from vendor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c80f952/core/java/android/os/RecoverySystem.java#121).

Comment: @Firelord So basically I'm screwed unless the vendor releases a zip update that fixes the RTL bug? Thanks for the comment btw

Comment: So I have another question: Let's say I load the vendor zip for my current android version, is it possible that this would revert the UI to default settings without erasing my data?

Comment: Addressing your second comment: it depends upon instructions in the zip.  If you're loading current Android version, then the problem you're having won't be resolved unless you format data partition which is akin to factory reset. While the code for that UI setting resides in system partition, the setting indicating your enabled developer option is stored inside data partition and that's from where the system reads the status and applies it.