# Forgot encryption password, too many wrong password attempts = wipe: Can I image my phone to "get more password tries" by restoring an image?

Tags: backup, encryption, restore, password

Forgot my Android encryption password, only have 10 tries left before data wipe, how can I backup my phone to get 10 more tries if I don't manage to find the password within 10 tries?

For context:

- ROM: **Lineage** 14 official build Custom recovery: **TWRP** **Bootloader:
  Unlocked** The phone is **not** rooted. No SD card port.

*The phone is encrypted with a password (not a PIN)

*I don't remember the exact encryption password, so I can't get past the password prompt after booting. But I am sure I can find it if I keep trying. It might take me more than 10 tries to enter all variations though.

*I can't access or mount /data from TWRP (nor can I get past the password promt after booting) without the password.

*After entering the wrong password multiple times, the password prompt says I only have 10 tries left before the data gets wiped, and I must avoid this at all costs. (Since Android 6 or 7, there is a limited number of tries before the phone gets wiped)

My question is: How can I make a backup of the phone in it's current state, so that even if I don't manage to enter the right password after booting the phone 10 times, I can restore the phone in it's current state and still have 10 more tries (and eventually repeat this if I still don't manage to find the password after 20 tries)?

I have found some tutorials that show how to backup /dev/block/mmcblk0, but they require root (I can't install anything in my phone since it's encrypted...). And I am not even sure if it will work to restore the phone in it's "10 tries left".

I also don't have access to /data partition from TWRP without entering the password (it shows "0MB") so I can't backup the /data partition from TWRP.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attempting to brute force Android security pattern through TWRP via adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212261/attempting-to-brute-force-android-security-pattern-through-twrp-via-adb)

Comment: you have TWRP for root access what more do you need? don't pull whole [mmcblk0](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218269) also do *not* try to wipe [locksettings.db](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216155) only *'adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata'* (and for [crypto footer](https://forensicswiki.xyz/wiki/index.php?title=How_To_Decrypt_Android_Full_Disk_Encryption#Locating_the_Encryption_Key) *efs/metadata partition* according to your */etc/recovery.fstab*)

Comment: If there is a solution somewhere which uses TWRP, than you don't have to worry about having a rooted device/Android. TWRP already gives you root access.