# How to turn HTC Widfire with blank screen into debug mode

Tags: usb-debugging, htc-wildfire

My screen on HTC Wildfire has gone blank and so have got my phone upgraded. Whilst the guy in the shop was able to transfer my pictures and video, when he tried to transfer my contact phone numbers he said he couldn't do that without putting the phone into debug mode, and he could only do that if he could see what he was doing on the screen.

Is there any way of getting a HTC Wildfire into debug mode without having to use the screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/12442) (but judging from there, the answer is "no").

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts are saved in Google contacts and your photos and video in SD card.

Comment: Nick didn't write whether he had his contacts synced, so you cannot be sure of the first part, roxan. Further, pictures and videos already have been obtained according to the question text. Apart from that, nothing left of your answer -- sorry ;)

Comment: Maybe after looking at my answer he'll check Google contacts and find the contacts there. :D

Comment: Admitted, chances are good -- if he returns to check for answers :)