# How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, usb, usb-debugging, broken-screen

I dropped my Samsung S3. Now I cannot see anything, just a white screen with purple, black, and green lines. Before it blanked out, it wasn't recognizing my finger touch. Any idea on how or what to repair? I want to save my phone so I can backup all my data.

Screen has a small crack on the lower right part of the screen:

- the colors are all messed up
- can't press anything
- can be turned on and can hear the starting sound
- can still receive calls and text
- USB debugging WAS NOT ENABLED

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb)

Answer (score 4):

install [kies](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/#none) and connect your phone with usb cable.  Then go to backup/restore and you can easily backup your important data from there.

Comment: This software only runs on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Also doesn't work if USB debugging is not enabled, as OP stated.

Comment: Looks like Kies doesn't work on phones made in 2017 or later.

Answer (score 3):

FOUND A FIX!!!!! Hi Everyone, I just experienced the same thing: my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 was dropped and the LCD stopped working. However, the phone would turn on. I could not receive calls or call out. My USB Debugging was turned off. This is how I managed to retrieve my TEXTS, other Rooted info and normal files. I am not sure if the front end of this fix had much to do with the over-all fix, but it seemed to.

1. I turned my phone on. I pressed my "Volume Up" button until I heard it beep. While still pressing the volume button, I pressed the "Bottom Face" button, then my "On/Off" button. Pressing them all down at the same time, but in that order. This seemed to put the phone in recovery mode.
2. I went to this website and downloaded Kies 3 software from Samsung (free). http://www.mobile-phone-transfer.com/extract-data-from-kies-backup-sbu-file.html
3. I opened the software and then plugged my Old phone in. DO NOT plug your phone in until the program is opened. Choose the files you want to backup and then press the backup button (may be called something else, but you get my point)
4. Once the backup is complete, plug your new phone in and restore all of the selected files (you may choose which ones) onto your new phone.

It worked with no worries about the "USB Debugging" being turned on or off!!!!!!!!!!!!!Yahooooooooo.

I wanted to share this as not other option worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Does *NOT* work without USB debugging on.

Comment: @Blairg23 seems to have worked though...

Comment: @Nearoo have you tried it? I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like Kies was discontinued and does not work with devices made after 2016 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for putting this on an old thread, however having spent a week paining over how to do this if your screen is locked and totally broken. Buy a USB OTG cable from Amazon (they're quite cheap), plug a USB keyboard into this and then plug that into your phone. You should be able to type the PIN to unlock it if this is what you have, then you can use Kies to backup the phone. Just worked for me (yay). *This method only works on certain devices.*

Answer (score -2):

I broke the display and digitizer today on my Galaxy S4, without USB Debugging turned on. I used [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/) to backup everything on the internal storage, apps, music, ringtones and their settings, text messages, contacts, all of it.

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/67370/96277) already tells us to use Kies. Consider telling us the point in adding redundancy on the page.

Comment: KIES does *NOT* work without USB debugging enabled.

Answer (score -3):

Not possible if debugging is disabled.

Comment: Why not? The answer suggesting Kies shows it is. ADB Backups is not the only backup method available (though I'd trust it more than Kies). So can you please [edit] your answer and elaborate on the reasoning?

Comment: @lzzy as OP confirm that, USB debugging was not enabled, and Blairg23 tells in comments that kies does not work without usb debugging. So can you please delete your comment and elaborate on the reasoning?