# recevering data from broken screen on micromax yureka having broken screen

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

MY screen of Micromax Yureka is broken and I can't see anything, Plus my usb debugging is off. Is there any way to recover data?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Please see our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) (scroll down to the "data recovery" section). You'll even find a similar question there: [How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/67352/16575) (but unfortunately, the answers there won't help you much as they are Samsung specific, using *Kies* for that). But checking the others should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

A non-device specific approach would be to access your device through adb.

This route requires you to have a custom recovery already installed on your device.

Boot your device into recovery mode.
Connect to pc, open a terminal, and execute the following...

adb shell mount /data
adb shell mount /system

From there you can, if you need to, pull the entire /data partition [most anyway] Symlinks and some firmware files may error out.

adb pull /data

and so forth. If you have permission denied when pulling,run the following,
adb shell mount -o rw,remount /data

No. You can not do this with a stock recovery though Yureka might be different.