# Android recover data (adb device unauthorized)

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, broken-screen

I am trying to recover data from my phone (Galaxy S3 mini) which screen is cracked. I want to do this using adb. But my device is unauthorized.

How can I solve this? I don't have acess to the device directly therefore I'm not able to turn on USB debugging.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
    List of devices attached
    007667324ccb229b        unauthorized
```

Comment: Your phone has to have "USB Debugging" checking in Settings - Developer Options.  When you run an adb command, your phone should pop up a window to allow it to be authorized when using adb, you have to check the checkbox and hit OK.  I would assume if you haven't done this, you may not be able to w/ a broken screen.

Comment: Screen is completely dead(cracked).... No other way to do this?

Comment: Jacob, please check our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info). Your question seems to be covered at least partly e.g. by [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575) and [How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/67352/16575) The other links might also be useful to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem entering the recovery mode by pressing "home", "volume up" and "power" buttons at the same time.

Once in recovery mode adb recognized my device and I was able to use the command `adb pull /sdcard/` which copied the sdcard to content to my PC