# How to recover data off a broken phone?

Tags: samsung, broken-screen

i have a samsung galaxy grand 2 which have a broken screen that isnt responsive at all, and im desperate to get some important files and images off of it, but the problem is usb debugging is off, its locked with a pin and doesnt support an OTG, i havent tried to use ADB commands yet cause i dont have any experience and the phone doesnt have a custom recovery either, but its flashed from jellybean to kitkat. i will be very appreciated if someone can give me a solution?? what kind of options i have here?

Comment: Have you checked the [broken screen wiki page](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)?

Comment: If USB Debugging is Off, you can't connect to ADB..

Comment: The only method, if you don't care about the phone is to try and install a custom recovery.  Then you can backup the data...

Answer (score 1):

### **After assessing your situation closely !**

You only have 1 option.
The fact that you have no OTG, means no access is possible to enable ADB.. You also can not access it in any other way.

A few years ago, ADB would automatically be enabled on every boot, the system would then boot up and configure ADB as per user settings... This allows many root access programs to work correctly ( the reason most repeatedly restart the device )   ...

You may have to write a script for running batch commands,  You can do this easily on Windows

```
adb restart
adb wait-for-device    
adb pull /storage/sdcard0
```

A simple script used to exploit the vulnerability...

You would save that text file as commands.bat   ( .bat is a batch file )  and run it...

This probably won't work however...

Your only option I could find, cost money and time.

[LCD & Digitizer - Front panel replacement](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=samsung%20galaxy%20prime%202%20lcd)

Replace the whole front panel yourself...

People have already Assembled the entire front LCD & Digitizer, so no hassles trying to pry the screen off...

You just,

- unscrew the old back
- Take the back half off
- Plug in the new front half   ( LCD & Digitizer panel )
- Screw it back together

  ...
  It's fairly cheap to do it yourself...

This answer is not a guide but just an example of possible solution's.. Please be careful and take all necessary precautions whenever taking apart electrical devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could access phone data with ADB.
[This](https://www.fonecope.com/enable-usb-debugging-android-broken-screen.html#Solution%203) should provide enough information.
[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130413/android-recover-data-adb-device-unauthorized) also may cover your question.

There are also quite a few apps that (allegedly) allow you accessing your data. I had not tried any of these, but see examples:

https://www.androidphonesoft.com/resources/enable-usb-debugging-android-broken-screen.html

https://www.fonepaw.com/usb/enable-usb-debugging-screen-broken-android.html

https://www.coolmuster.com/android/recover-samsung-without-usb-debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

### Considering you have a locked device, that also has no access to ADB.

### Don't Bother With

### • ADB

### • FASTBOOT

---

**Your only chance is Odin**

This is a tutorial for noobs or members who are new to Rooting and want to root their phone.

Downloads:
*Odin 3 v3.0.9 
*CWM recovery thread(Downloads available for 4.3  and 4.4 also)
*SuperSU

Steps to root your phone:
1) Download the first two files given above to     your laptop/PC.
2) Turn off your phone.
3) Go to download mode (by pressing Vol.down+home+power buttons at the same time for about 7-8 secs)
4)Open the ODIN file you downloaded on your laptop/pc.
5) Connect your phone to your laptop/PC through USB cable.
6) When ODIN detects your phone, the ID:COM area will become yellow/blue.
7) In ODIN click on PDA and then select the recovery file you downloaded. Also tick the check box beside PDA(if there is any)
8) Click on start. The flashing process will start.
9) If the flashing succeeds, ODIN will show 'PASS'.
 That means the recovery flashed successfully. Yay!!!

10) Now turn on your phone and download the third file and place it in your external SD card.
11) Turn off your phone.
12) Reboot to recovery(by pressing Vol.up+home+power buttons).
13) The recovery will start. You have to navigate by volume buttons and power button.
Vol.up - move up
Vol.down - move down
Power button - select option
14) Select 'install zip'.
15) Select 'Choose zip from ext_sd or external SD card'.
16)Select the third file you downloaded. Flashing process will start.
17) After it finishes, go back and reboot your phone.

It's upon you, of you want to follow this:

18)Use Knox Remover to remove all Knox files.

Enjoy your rooted Galaxy grand 2!!! Now you can flash other recoveries or flash other custom ROMs or custom kernels.

**Some useful tips(Experimental/WIP)**: 
You can use Triangle Away to reset       the flash counter after flashing ROMs and make your device status from custom to official. This is a really useful app. Report here if it works. You needn't download from google play, you can scroll down and download from the attachments.

**CREDITS**:
@shabbypenguin: For CWM recovery.
@Chainfire: For SuperSU and Triangle Away.
@AL_IRAQI: For Knox remover.

*REFERENCES*
[xda-developers.com.../guide-easily-root-galaxy-grand-2-sm-t2812807](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-grand-2/general/guide-easily-root-galaxy-grand-2-sm-t2812807)

---

**After Getting CWM Recovery, DO NOT FOLLOW THE OTHER STEPS, THEY'RE SPECIFICALLY FOR ROOT ACCESS**

- Open CWM and Backup Data from Internal Memory...
- Open the backup on your PC, it may need to be extracted with another software like 7Zip.
- Extract precious data from the internal storage ... DATA/MEDIA/EMULATED/ - or similar.

Comment: Hello, Sorry for the delay but my phone is actually already rooted by a one click root app, it have been like that always but yeah i thought of getting a custom recovery but how will i do that? i have actually struggled on finding the no touch custom recovery for samsung galaxy grand 2. and again thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You can find many recovery porting guide's online, I've personally only ever had luck porting MTK processors so I can't be much help in that direction... I'm currently running a custom port of TWRP 3.0.2 that I managed to port in about an hour... The trick is to ignore your devices name and look for CPU specific porting guide's.. It also results in a lot more guide's...

Comment: Are you saying that i should look for CWM custom recovery that suits the CPU not the actual Grand 2? seriously all the links for CWM recovery for grand 2 are broken.

Comment: Try TWRP and a Keyboard & Mouse to control it... Access the File Manager and copy your needed data to an SD Card.. Then take out the card and put it into a computer..https://duckduckgo.com/?q=samsung+galaxy+grand+2+twrp ....