# How to download everything off broken Samsung when screen won't turn on?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5, downloading, broken-screen

Last week I dropped and broke my Samsung galaxy s5. The screen won't turn on, but it vibrates/rings whenever I get a call or message, so I know the phone still works. All I want is to download my photos and notes onto my computer. How do I do this?

Also, I've read that I'm meant to allow USB debugging, but since I can't use my screen is there a way to do it on the computer instead of via settings?

Thanks!!

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67352/how-to-backup-broken-screen-phone-when-usb-debugging-is-not-enabled

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Friendly hint: Most of our tags have useful wiki pages attached to them. Have you already checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)? If none of the hints there work out for you: What Android version is running on the device? Does it have a Google account set up? Is it connected to any network (mobile or WiFi)?

Answer (score 0):

1. connect it to PC/MAC
2. open file explorer or finder
3. find the phone
4. folder should be DCIM