# Install app without touchscreen or ADB?

Tags: adb, touchscreen, vnc

My phones **digitizer** seems to have **gone bad** (after 5hrs of few app updates and 3hrs of a fall, working twice after that for 10minutes). It doesn't seems that the USB Debugging option is enabled on the phone, due to which I **can't access phone using ADB**.

I intend to **install a VNC server app** on my phone and use it to control the phone through my Laptop. Then try and isolate the apps to rule out if the apps caused the issue.

Is it **possible** to install an app in my case**?**

There are no passwords or screen locks set. Also just the power and volume buttons are working. I can go to Fasboot & Recovery mode but can't select any option. :(

Please note: No data connection is turned on. So I can't install any remote app using Google Play store.

Comment: Which phone do you have?

Comment: Micromax A116 with Android 4.1.x

Comment: This link has commands to connect but it uses Linux with installed uudecode. I have Win7. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb

Answer (score 4):

Check if you can connect a mouse (or Keyboard) through USB OTG port (and microUSB-to-USB converter cable)...

I'm not sure whether your device supports OTG or not... Just give a try...

Comment: (Also, a keyboard if you really don't have an USB mouse around)

Comment: @domen Yeah. That's right!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the phone is connected to the internet, you can install apps from the Google Play web interface](https://play.google.com/store/apps) without touching the phone.

Starting the app is a different matter, though: you may need to find an app that's specifically designed for this situation, so it can be triggered without needing to open it from the launcher, or use a USB gamepad (or a Bluetooth one, if it's already paired) to control the launcher without using the touchscreen.

Comment: No data connection ON. :( Or I would have installed VNC server app till now and gotten out of this mess.

Comment: @Jay You need to add this information to your question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Answer (score 0):

Try with shell using a keyboard

```
pm install [path_to_apk]
```

Comment: So how do you get a shell in the first place without the touchscreen or ADB?