# Cannot access galaxy nexus via adb

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-nexus, data-recovery, broken-screen, aokp

Yesterday my noble [Galaxy Nexus (maguro)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus) sacrificed itself to save me when I fell from my mountain bike.

I would like to copy the data to my computer. What is good: the screen and the sim card is broken, but the rest of the phone seems to be still working.

When I plug in the phone on my Linux (Debian) computer, it is detected as multimedia device. However, I cannot access the data, as I would need to unlock the screen (which is broken).

Alternatively, I tried to access the phone using the adb-tools. However, the device is not listed:

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

I can see my phone in lsusb:

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 04e8:685c Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9250 Phone [Galaxy Nexus]
...
```

I tried some different stuff, like generating a `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file, but this didn't help.

I also tried to boot the phone to the bootloader, but I didn't succeed - maybe the connection to the volume buttons is broken.

Some additional information that may help: my Galaxy Nexus runs [AOKP](http://aokp.co/) and [Clockworkmod](https://www.clockworkmod.com/) is installed.

Comment: Do you remember if you had USB Debugging enabled?  Without it, ADB won't work.  Also, look here for help enabling it: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb

Comment: I think yes, but I don't know exactly... Is there a different way if it's not enabled?

Comment: Have you tried booting to recovery (or do you mean that by "bootloader")? As you're running a custom ROM, you certainly have a custom recovery installed. Those often (usually? always?) have debugging enabled by default. You might need to mount the partitions you want to recover data from manually then, though.

Comment: I tried to boot into recovery (yes, that's what I mean with booloader). However, it seems the volume rocker is broken as well so I can at least not confirm that the phone was booting to recovery. But it should be possible to overcome the issue of the broken volume rocker, so I'm quite confident that I will manage to boot to recovery.

Answer (score 0):

As your device is rooted I assume you can download nexus root toolkit to pull and push files, it automatically handles both, bootloader booting and fastboot, through adb, if however you didn't have usb debugging enabled I cant help you.