# Does AOKP have USB-Debugging activated per default?

Tags: usb-debugging, aokp

The screen of my Galaxy Nexus is broken (also see [Cannot access galaxy nexus via adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/80767/cannot-access-galaxy-nexus-via-adb)).

It seems like USB-debugging was deactivated, so my only way to recover the data is to flash a rom on the phone that has USB-debugging activated per default. I think this should work using fastboot.

At the moment the device has AOKP installed. If I reflash AOKP on the phone, will USB-debugging be activated?

In other words: Does AOKP have USB-debugging activated per default?

Comment: Recovery often has debugging enabled by default, I'd try that first before flashing anything. Running a custom ROM usually implies a custom recovery as well, right? ;)

Comment: Good suggestion, I will try that first. Yes, I have ClockworkMod installed.

Comment: Should do (I have that on some devices as well; never tried *acessing* it via ADB in recovery, but saw it listed via `adb devices`). Keep us updated (maybe with an answer when solved? ;) Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I keep you updated. However, if I cannot use adb in recovery, it would still be interesting if an AOKP-image would have USB-debugging activated per default or not... Of course I could also flash another ROM (like Cyanogen Mod, which definitely has usb-debugging activated) but changing to another system would be a step I would rather not take in the current state of the device.

Comment: No, switching to a different ROM often requires wiping the device in order to have it booting successfully.

Comment: As you promised to keep us updated: did you succeed? Remember it's perfectly fine here to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't report back, @Izzy . The reason is, I didn't succeed (yet). I couldn't access the memory in recovery (maybe I couldn't even access the recovery because the volume keys are also damaged). I didn't have the time to investigate further. When I find a way, I will certainly answer my question. Sorry!

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I keep my fingers crossed then!