# Phone doesn't start. USB Debug is off, can't connect pc for recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

I have a *Huawei Ideos X5* phone. It is rooted. When I took the battery out and restarted it the other day, it didn't open: the device starts, shows the "Ice Cream Sandwich" logo – and there it stays (even when waiting for 7 hours).

I was going to try the recovery mode but, because *USB debugging* is switched off, my PC doesn't see the phone.

Is there any chance that I can change the debug mode without opening the phone? The phone is old but really want to save it.

Comment: Sorry for the really late answer. With didn't open, i meant as phone starts, shining Ice Cream Sandwich logo appears but it just stays like that. It even stayed like that for 7 hours or so.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I've integrated that with your question. Please take a look at [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575) and the questions linked to it.

Answer (score 2):

Boot into recovery mode by holding the Power & Volume Up buttons on your phone. (if Volume Up doesn't work, try Volume Down).

I've used this method to get an unresponsive device to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CWM recovery installed? If yes, then try going in CWM and format your phone from there. It may help.

Comment: It is installed but my main problem is that i can't connect my phone to pc while in recovery- pink mode.

Comment: You don't have to. Just goto the recovery mode by pressing appropriate buttons specific to your device. When you enter recovery mode, do a full data wipe.

Comment: Hussain, did you consider that wiping the device is not really the intention of recovering data, as the OP requests possibly? @STAR1B2UTY What Hussain is suggesting is a factory-reset. You might get your phone working that way, but lose all your data.

Comment: That is a problem too.When I press appropriate buttons specific to my device, I can't even see the options. Like rebooting or other stuff appears in the screen.That's what you're talking about right?It doesn't appear on the screen. I can only go into the pink screen.That's all.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Freezing. Your device has got freezed. You have 2 options:

1st option-

Remove battery
Then place it again in its place.
Then carefully hold the volume up or volume down button along with the power button. Your device will now boot in recovery mode.
Now using the volume keys navigate to factory reset and using power button reset it.
Now reboot again.

If it doesn't work then 2nd option will definitely work-

Download ROM for your phone by googling it.
Place the ROM in your Memory card.
Now again boot in recovery mode as described above.
Choose apply update from sdcard.
Navigate to that .zip file which is the ROM you downloaded.
Using power key select it.
Wait for some 15-20 minutes.
Hola. You are ready to go.

Note: The above steps will delete all your data in phone memory.