# Accessing internal storage on Moto G, locked phone, broken screen

Tags: adb, motorola-moto-g, android-sdk, broken-screen

my girlfriend dropped her Moto G and now the screen is completely black, the phone is secured with a lock pattern. It's very important for us to recover the pictures, because unfortunately they weren't backed up.

I'm a software dev, so don't hesitate to offer solutions that involve ADB, the Android SDK or anything else. Another important note, the phone is not in Debugging mode.

Comment: Is it possible to remotely enable USB Debugging?

Comment: See: [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575) (and our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done without unlocking the device. If the touchscreen still works try to boot the device, let it settle, press the power button to wake it up and then draw the pattern from memory. You can print a photo of the phone on the lockscreen and mark the point on the display as a reference.