# Busted Verizon Galaxy Note 5 screen, trying to use adb to unlock

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note, broken-screen

Recently, I dropped my Samsung Galaxy Note 5 and busted the glass, lcd, digitizer, and maybe the speaker. Before, I try anything with replacing the broken parts, I would like to get the SMS database and my photos off via usb cable. Unfortunately, I can't unlocked the screen and the adb devices shows nothing on both a Mac and Linux machines for me to send a command to simulate an unlock gesture. Also, I don't have usb debugging turned on and have no way to turn it on. As a last ditch attempt, I have tried to modify the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-rules to try to get adb working. Adb still couldn't find my phone.  I also have thought of going the OTG route but nobody that has a Verizon GalaxyNote5 has had any luck with that. What else can I try to get my data off of my phone? Fastboot?

My problem is similar to this except I don't have a Nexus phone:
[Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb)

Comment: "*and busted the glass, lcd, digitizer, and maybe the speaker.*" -- did you like drop it from *Burj Khalifa*? Anyhow, you may be able to [flash TWRP](https://twrp.me/devices/samsunggalaxynote5gsm.html) (a custom recovery) from download mode. If you achieve success in that, boot into recovery mode and adb should be able to detect the device as well as give unrestricted access to data.

Comment: Nothing that cool, I went out for pho and they had a tile floor.Will try the flash TWRP and report back.

Comment: TWRP is touch based... to even use the custom recovery idea you'll need CWM with a volume button user interface and a second device to learn the combinations that will get you through the backup menu. you also have the risk of having bootloader locked.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use **CWM or Philz Touch recovery** to make a full backup by just using the volume/power buttons.
- You can also use an OTG adapter and a **USB mouse/keyboard** to interact with the phone. If you can't see the screen either, you can use a MHL to HDMI adapter to hook up your screen output to the TV. You may or may not be able to use an OTG mouse or keyboard daisy-chained to the MHL adapter (depends on MHL adapter, unbranded one didn't work for me).
- If your bootloader is locked and MHL+mouse idea doesn't work out, your best bet is to get the phone fixed. I would recommend to buy a second phone with Bad ESN off ebay, and just swap the motherboards, with the amount of damage you have. Then you can resell the leftover parts.

Comment: Will try it and report back.

Comment: Ok, so I rebooted into the bootloader and turned on usb debugging. I was able to connect as a mass storage device from my mac and get my pictures off. I might do so more experiments in the future  to see if I can load the recovery firmware to get my SMS messages off. I was not able to get the OTG route to work with the HDMI option. :( Thanks for all your advice.