# Unlocking the screen of Nexus 4 from pc

Tags: nexus-4, usb-debugging, locked-out, broken-screen

I am trying to unlock myphone through pc as the screen is broken and does not work. For now only power and volume buttons work.

I tried looking around and found about ADK but whenever I tried to run adb shell it says "no device found". Although my device is connected to pc but it only shows the internal memory if its unlocked.

Secondly, I saw some suggestions to update the values of tables using sqlite3. I also tried to use sqlite3 to update and change values to enable usb debugging on cellphone and also tried to reset the gesture lock but was able to do so. 
I also have usb on the cable but I found out that Nexus 4 does not support usb mouse/keyboard.

For now I need to enable USB debugging somehow so I can use the mouse or keyboard.

Basically what I am trying to do is to enable usb-debugging on cellphone and unlock it. If I am able to do that then I would be able to use usb mouse
Is there any way to unlock and enable usb debugging through pc?

Comment: Are you using stock recovery `<3e>`?

Comment: Could you tell me more about this ? I havent use that so far

Comment: I've just added 2 more tags to your question. Please check with our [locked-out](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) and [broken-screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) tag-wikis, which both hold some background and first aid on the issue. Btw: Some formatting of your question cannot hurt (adding some line breaks at least ;)

Comment: Given that you do not know about that, I would only assume that your device has stock recovery installed. In that case, **note** that any attempt to enable USB debugging in Android OS would fail since that recovery doesn't grant shell access, let alone root access. You don't have any option as it seems since flashing a custom recovery would require unlocking bootloader which would wipe the device. Best is to factory reset the device now.

Comment: Probably related: [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb)

Comment: is it possible to unlock the cellphone through android system recovery?