# How can I enable USB debugging on Xperia Miro when touch is not working?

Tags: usb, debug

I have a Xperia Miro. I am trying to connect mouse with OTG cable, but it is not able to detect.

Touch is totally not working.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like the *Miro doesn't support Usb OTG* ([source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=36434369&postcount=3)) – though strangely, [Amazon offers a special cable for that](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00Q87JH6C). Could it be there are multiple Miros? The [ST23i is reported to support OTG](http://www.verygoodreview.com/android-phone/sony-xperia-miro-st23i-review.html), which somehow contradicts that XDA information. Which one do you have?

Comment: I hope the below thread helps: [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb)