# Activate Debugging on broken Nexus 7

Tags: adb, nexus-7, usb-debugging, broken-screen

My Nexus 7's touch screen is completely broken, I know I can manipulate the device using adb commands, but debugging mode isn't enabled on the devices. Is there anyway to enable debugging mode from a PC or any easy way that wont break any files, I would preferably like to just turn on debugging mode and not have to reset the device or anything, cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you seen [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575) (plus the questions linked/related to it)? Did it help, or where you've got stuck there?

Comment: I'm trying to like out it in debug mode without doing any of that stuff, is it possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. How should that work? In order to enable debugging you need to access the device somehow.

Comment: That was my thoughts just was hoping there would be an easier solution thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2):

With broken touch screen you won't be able to enable **USB debugging mode** using your PC.

**Tried Solution:**

I had tried the adb method but it doesn't ends well, however you can try to take a backup of your phone as described in [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575).

Well if you are going with my Solution **No Need to Backup**. Since Nexus 7 supports OTG (On the Go) connections, you can always connect your Mouse/Keyboard/Secondary Storages using your OTG Cable.

So try to Connect your Mouse using the OTG cable available for your device, then Go to your Settings and Enable USB Debugging mode.

That's all. Hope it will Help.