# Enable USB Debugging Android Dead Screen

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, usb-debugging, broken-screen

I obtained a Nexus 6 with a dead screen. I am trying to cast the screen to my computer. In order to do so, I believe I need to have USB Debugging enabled (which is presumably off).

I managed to [boot into recovery mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/175747/enabling-adb-on-nexus-6-with-dead-screen/176138#176138)

I tried to follow: [How to enable USB Debugging in Android if forgotten pattern for screen-unlock?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112040/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-if-forgotten-pattern-for-screen-unlock)

but for some reason /data is empty.

I have mounted /system
and added appended various lines to build files (link needed)

I am using twrp-3.1.1-0-shamu.img recovery image. When I boot (via fastboot) this image I can use ADB.

I have an OTG cable, mouse and keyboard but I doubt they will be helpful since I cannot see the screen

Comment: It may sound stupid, but when you noticed /data was empty in recovery mode did you make sure that Data partition was mounted already?

Comment: BTW, does WebKey not work for you? https://webkey.cc/

Comment: @Firelord I tried to mount it but it wasn't in fstab.

Comment: @Firelord I don't know how to install an app in recovery mode so I don't know how I would use webkey.cc

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=66731042&postcount=260

Comment: @MarkYisri Thanks for the link. I've seen variations all over that didn't work. Maybe this one will. Will try