# How to enable usb debugging on my broken touch screen android phone from windows 10 computer?

Tags: adb, usb-debugging, broken-screen

My android(Kitkat 4.4.2) phone's touch screen is broken, but phone is working fine.But usb debugging is disable. FIY, my sd card isn't working (I don't care about that) and my phone doesn't support OTG. All I need is to turn on the usb debugging. I tried to install some apk that is supposed to enable usb debugging from adb on phones recovery mode=> apply update from adb=> "adb sideload ".But it did not worked! Says (on phone) 'Installation aborted'
 Is there any simple command to enable usb debugging?
Or is there any other way?

Comment: Have you already checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](/tags/broken-screen/info)?

Comment: Yes! One of the topic in this fact is https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb -whic required sdk card. But as I told my can't read sd card.

Comment: No such thing as an "SDK card". In fact, the top-rated answer is on a Nexus 5, which doesn't have an SD card. SDK is the Software Development Kit which you probably have installed anyway if you use ADB. Please check that answer again. If you cannot find a CWM image for your device, TWRP is another option which should work the same.

Comment: Sorry! it should be sd card! Simply a mistake! I know what is sdk, by the way! Thanks very much.

Comment: I had a similar problem on one of my KitKat devices, The solution was to do a factory reset therefore changing USB Debugging back to enabled, i then had enough time to repair the device before it fully booted up and automatically disabled USB Debugging again, This may not be helpful because some devices disable USB Debugging on release and therefore can not be enabled with a factory reset.

Comment: @Zillinium this has another draw-back: factory-reset will delete all data. So if the idea behind it is to backup data, this approach won't work. If however the intention is just "second use", it's a different thing.